# map.fire("customEvent"); Howto fire a custom event in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

It's the first time I'm trying to make a Leaflet plugin (also first time with Github).

With the plugin you can select a box on a map. When the box is drawn, I want to fire an event.

I can launch an event like:

```
map.fire("selected");
```

and then I can see it in my script with

```
map.on("selected", function() { .... });
```

But what about firing a custom event like:

**`map.fire("areaSelected").`**

I tried to search in the Documentation, but didn't find a way...

A jsFiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zoutepopcorn/UQ9G2/5/)
The github page: [Github](https://github.com/zoutepopcorn/leaflet.areaselect/blob/master/AreaSelect.js)

Answer (score 0):

There's an unrelated error that's breaking this jsfiddle:

[image]

Comment: OK, strange. Maybe it was the old fiddle. 
I only get the error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fire' of undefined" 
when I'm resize the square.
It's because I cant fire events like
map.fire("test"); or 
map.fire("areaSelected");

Thank you for your help. http://jsfiddle.net/zoutepopcorn/UQ9G2/5/ doesnt fire the above error

Comment: That isn't a problem with 'fire': you're not correctly managing the `map` variable, so it's undefined when you're trying to call it. Please read other [plugins](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox.js/blob/mb-pages/src/grid_layer.js) that [correctly manage the map reference](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/825b23ccf284df7f2e39853a804c4702e166df6c/src/draw/handler/Draw.Feature.js) rather than juggling it as a global.